# write an asynchronous http client using twisted framework

Tags: python, twisted, event-driven

i want to write an asynchronous http client using twisted framework which fires 5 requests asynchronously/simultaneously to 5 different servers. Then compare those responses and display a result. Could someone please help regarding this.

Comment: Do you have to use twisted?  You can make requests asynchronously with out twisted.

Answer (score 2):

For this situation I'd suggest using [`treq`](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [`DeferredList`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#deferredlist) to aggregate the responses then fire a callback when all the URLs have been returned. Here is a quick example:

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, task

def fetchURL(*urls):
    dList = []
    for url in urls:
        d = treq.get(url)
        d.addCallback(treq.content)
        dList.append(d)
    return defer.DeferredList(dList)

def compare(responses):
    # the responses are returned in a list of tuples
    # Ex: [(True, b'')]
    for status, content in responses:
        print(content)

def main(reactor):
    urls = [ 
        'http://swapi.co/api/films/schema',
        'http://swapi.co/api/people/schema',
        'http://swapi.co/api/planets/schema',
        'http://swapi.co/api/species/schema',
        'http://swapi.co/api/starships/schema',
        ]
    d = fetchURL(*urls)     # returns Deferred
    d.addCallback(compare)  # fire compare() once the URLs return w/ a response
    return d                # wait for the DeferredList to finish

task.react(main)
# usually you would run reactor.run() but react() takes care of that
```

In the `main` function, a list of URLs are passed into `fecthURL()`. There, each site will make an async request and return a `Deferred` that will be appended to a `list`. Then the final list will be used to create and return a `DeferredList` obj. Finally we add a callback (`compare()` in this case) to the `DeferredList` that will access each response. You would put your comparison logic in the `compare()` function.

Answer (score -2):

You don't necessarily need `twisted` to make asynchronous http requests.  You can use python threads and the wonderful `requests` package.

```
from threading import Thread
import requests


def make_request(url, results):
    response = requests.get(url)
    results[url] = response


def main():
    results = {}
    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        url = 'http://webpage/{}'.format(i)
        t = Thread(target=make_request, kwargs={'url': url, 'results': results})
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads():
        t.join()

    print results
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is better suited as a comment. OP may already have a twisted setup. Also thread and asynchronous IO are NOT same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  but the requirements are such that i need to do it using it using twisted.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it will block waiting for each thread to finish. Though it still wouldn't make your question correct, ``requests`` has support for ``gevent`` which should eliminate the ``.join()`` calls atleast. To use a similar approach in twisted, you could use ``deferToThread()`` to run each request in a thread